# I get an error when i compile

Tags: c#, wpf

I get a new error after I've made the changes suggested in the post below. You can find there details regarding the error (see image1). Do you know how I can fix this?

[How to declare a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862000/how-to-declare-a-constructor/22862359?noredirect=1#22862359)

http://i58.tinypic.com/qwwqvn.png

EDIT:
Sorry, i'm new here so i don't really know how things go. in the previous post, someone advised me to make a new post with a link to that problem. I will now be offering enough details so that you can understand what is going on.

I have 3 errors that i wish to solve...

The code to those errors is posted below

"Argument 1: cannot convert from 'object' to 'string'"

"Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Media.Brush' to 'string'"

"'Microsoft.Samples.Kinect.ControlsBasics.SelectionDisplay.SelectionDisplay(string, string)' has some invalid arguments"

```
public SelectionDisplay(string itemId, string Tag)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.messageTextBlock.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,Properties.Resources.SelectedMessage,itemId);

    }


 var files = Directory.GetFiles(@".\GalleryImages");

            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                FileInfo fileInfo = new FileInfo(file);

                BitmapImage bi = new BitmapImage();
                bi.BeginInit();
                bi.UriSource = new Uri(file, UriKind.Relative);
                bi.EndInit();

                var button = new KinectTileButton
                {
                    Label = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file),
                    Background = new ImageBrush(bi),
                    Tag = file
                };
                var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
                this.wrapPanel.Children.Add(button);
            }


  private void KinectTileButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        var button = (KinectTileButton)e.Source;
        var image = button.CommandParameter as BitmapImage;
        var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label,button.Background); // aici poti apoi sa mai trimiti si imaginea ca parametru pentru constructor
        this.kinectRegionGrid.Children.Add(selectionDisplay);
        e.Handled = true;

    }
```

thank you for your understanding and i hope the post will get reopened.

Comment: You seem to only have one constructor defined, but you call using two different sets of parameters. Either define both constructors, or call it consistently.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you have called the constructor for SelectionDisplay two different ways:

```
var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label as string, button.Tag as string);
var selectionDisplay = new SelectionDisplay(button.Label,button.Background); // aici poti apoi sa mai trimiti si imaginea ca parametru pentru constructor
```

The first takes two strings, the second an object and a brush (as the errors you encountered indicate). This means that you need two constructors:

```
public class SelectionDisplay
{
    public SelectionDisplay(string itemId, string Tag)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        this.messageTextBlock.Text = string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,Properties.Resources.SelectedMessage,itemId);

    }

    public SelectionDisplay(object label, Brush background)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

Now, you may want to consider only having one constructor, but you need to then make sure that you always call it with the same argument types.

Let me know if I can clarify anything!

Comment: You are passing a brush, but accepting a button. Accept a brush (as in my example) instead.

Comment: http://i60.tinypic.com/2jba3i9.png http://i59.tinypic.com/wcnwuv.png  http://i57.tinypic.com/2eyxcvm.png  I've solved the errors but when I click the button it doesn't work as I want it to, i.e. nothing happens. It should open a new window (blue) and in that window the selected image should be displayed. For example, if I select the Koala from the image list, in the next window the koala image should be displayed, and next to it, a short description. Please look at the images

Comment: Well, you need something besides my sample code in your constructors :). The code provided was intended to solve the compilation issue, not write your program for you! You already have the code to set an image source in code, so in each constructor you should do so, and also update your text appropriately. Do you have something specific that isn't working? Any new issues should likely be a new question, but you will need to narrow your scope a little bit.