# Initialize list inside of public class

Tags: c#

I have this:

```
public class GetList {

    public List< KeyValuePair< string, string > > errors {
        get; set;
    }
}
```

I would like to know how to add a constructor to get a new instance of the class and a new list to which I can add values

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847195/how-do-i-create-a-custom-class-with-a-constructor

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22862000/how-to-declare-a-constructor

Comment: You mean, need to capture all errors to your list?

Comment: Yes that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Constructors are defined like so:

```
class ClassNameGoesHere {

    public ClassNameGoesHere() {
        // this is the constructor
    }
}
```

You can initialize your `errors` property in the constructor:

```
class ClassNameGoesHere {

    public ClassNameGoesHere() {

        this.errors = new List< KeyValuePair< string, string > >();
    }
}
```

However you should conform to C# idiomatic programming by making collection properties `readonly` (this doesn't mean the collection is immutable, it just prevents external code from replacing the collection entirely) as well as using established naming and capitalization conventions.

I would also use `Tuple<String,String>` instead of `KeyValuePair<K,V>` or define my own element type.

You can set a read-only property using a property initializer, which is equivalent to putting it in the constructor, but makes the code more compact, so the explicit constructor can be eliminated completely:

This is how I would do it:

```
class ClassNameGoesHere {

    public List<Tuple<String,String>> Errors { get; } = new List<Tuple<String,String>>();
}
```

Comment: As a follow up question, how would I access the values of errors from another project?  Thanks!